# How to publish a JAVA desktop application using a SQLite database

Tags: java, database, sqlite, desktop-application, publishing

I mean which files should I provide to the end-user to execute the application correctly?

I can run the app on my development system using only the `myapp.jar` & `myapp.db` files in the same folder. But when I tried to share it with a friend he couldn't load the database..

Should I include the `sqlite.dll` or `sqlite.exe` files as well into the application directory?

*Note:* the database is used for retrieving AND storing data during runtime.

**Edit:**
Its a SWING application so I have a popup error to appear when the database or its schema are missing.
Here's the code:

> ```
> public boolean DBExists(Connection con,String dbName) {
>   Statement stmt = null;
>     ResultSet res = null;     
>     try
>   {
>       String sql = "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE TYPE='table';";
>       stmt = con.createStatement();
>         res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
>   }
>   catch(SQLException e)
>   {
>       System.out.println("Error creating or running SELECT statement: " + e.toString());
>   }
>     try {
>       if (res.next()) {
>           System.out.println("Database checked!");
>           return true;
>       } else {
>           System.out.println("Database doesnt exist!");
>           return false;
>       }
>     } catch (SQLException e) {
>       System.out.println("Error processing results: " + e.toString());
>     }
>     System.out.println("Problem while checking database availability.");
>     return false;
> }
> ```

The "Database doesn't exist!" message is triggered.

**Edit #2:**

Here's also the connection method which calls the DBExist() check:

```
public Connection DBConnect() {
    //STEP 1: Setup the Driver
    try
    {
        //Load the JDBC driver class dynamically.
        Driver d = (Driver)Class.forName(DRIVER).newInstance();
        DriverManager.registerDriver(d);
        System.out.println("Driver loaded successfuly!");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error loading database driver: " + e.toString());
        return null;
    }

    //STEP 2: Create connection to database using database URL
    Connection con;
    try
    {
        //FIXME: Load database filename via external config.
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL);
        System.out.println("Database connection successfull!");
        if (!DBExists(con,DB_NAME)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "Database file was not found!",
                    "Database Fatal Error",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error creating connection: " + e.toString());
        return null;
    }
    return con;          
}
```

Comment: Which SQLite interface are you using? Does it package the sqlite native libs (like the Xerial one does) or does it use unpackaged libs or is it pure java?

Comment: I'm using the Xerial JDBC indeed which I packed into the runnable jar using the Eclipse export. I also thought that was enough..

Comment: What specific exception is showing up when you try and run on a different machine?

Comment: I added the full code. The problem is I cannot access the console output while running on a different machine (I dont know how..) so I could check if an exception is triggered or just there's a problem with the .db file. Should I change the code to parse exceptions to GUI? Are you sure that the files included are enough?

Comment: I'd have him run the jar file with `java -jar myapp.jar` from the command line and see if you can have him send you the exception.

Comment: @Femi Thanks for the interest and the advice. Case solved before it even existed.. >.<

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok my friend is an idiot.. The app is running like a charm on two different machines.

Probably he didnt put the `.db` file in the same directory in the first place and running the `.jar` all alone created an empty database schema which triggered the error message.

So for anyone else asking the same:

**NO** there is no need to include `sqlite.exe` or `sqlite.dll` while publishing a desktop JAVA app using a SQLite database. Just pack the *JDBC driver* with the runnable `.jar` and the app executes fine.

Comment: I am also going to develop small desktop java app, N worried about same, So while using sqlLite in app, Is there any thing shoud we take care about on client PC ? Provide link how to pakging App ?